# Moving List of Specific Files From Folder-to-Folder in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having to move 30,000+ files manually and am trying to figure out how I can do this by VBA. I managed to obtain all of the file names by a VBA directory name pull, but am struggling with the transfer process.

My Excel file is as follows:

Column A - "File Name"
Example --> "File Title".pdf  (Could be a different file ext.)

Column B - "Source Folder Directory"
Example --> C:\Users\"user"\folder\folder\folder\EFT\Countries_COMPLETE\Wave 3\folder\SOURCEFOLDER

Column C - "Destination Folder Directory"
Example --> C:\Users\"user"\folder\folder\folder\EFT\Countries_COMPLETE\Wave 3\folder\folder\DESTINATIONFOLDER

I keep on getting getting a runtime 1004 even though all my objects are specificed.

```
Sub FileTranspose()

    Dim c As Excel.Range
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strDir As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        '// Loop from row 2 to last used cell in Col A
        For Each c In **Sheet1**.Range("A2").Resize(**Sheet1**.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

            '// If the cell contains any text...
            If c.Value <> vbNullString Then

                '// And the 2 cells to the right contain some text...
                If c.Offset(0, 1).Value <> vbNullString And c.Offset(0, 2).Value <> vbNullString Then

                    '// Make up the full source file name, includes path.
                    strName = c.Offset(0, 1).Value & IIf(Right$(c.Offset(0, 1).Value, 1) <> "\", "\", vbNullString) & c.Value
                    '// Same for destination Directory name
                    strDir = c.Offset(0, 2).Value & IIf(Right$(c.Offset(0, 2).Value, 1) <> "\", "\", vbNullString)

                    '// If the file to copy exists...
                    If Dir(strName) <> vbNullString Then

                        '// And the Destination directory exists...
                        If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
                            '// Copy it.
                            FileCopy strName, strDir & c.Value

                            '// Delete
                            Kill strName

                        End If

                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

The goal would be to automatically pull up column B, look for the file in column A, then insert into column C.

I would like to REMOVE the file from the original folder once copied over.

Comment: What line are you receiving the error on?

Comment: @Mike -->  Line: For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

Comment: @Mike even if you have to rewrite it, it would not bother me, i just need to get this thing to work at this point.

Comment: @AndrasDorko you sly fox ;) thank you, as you can tell it has been a long day ... long week and only wednesday! if anyone needs the edit with the declaration.. see my edit

Comment: @AndrasDorko hmm, not sure, because I did make it option explicit. See my edit above on the fix

Comment: @AndrasDorko     
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
 .. End With

Comment: Alright then, I guess now we are on the same page, one way or antoher but it is fixed now.